# Can't center the links in navbar with logo on the left

Tags: css, hyperlink, navbar, center

I'm trying to center the links in navbar with logo on the left, but nothing works - how can I do this? Everything either shifts too much to the right or doesn't want to shift at all.

I will be very thankful for any help.

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #333;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: gold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="logo" href="index.htm"><img src="styles/logo.png"></a>
  <a href="1.htm">Menu 1</a>
  <a href="2.htm">Menu 2</a>
  <a href="3.htm">Menu 3</a>
  <a href="4.htm">Menu 4</a>
  <a href="5.htm">Menu 5</a>
  <a href="6.htm">Menu 6</a>
  <a href="7.htm">Menu 7</a>
  <a href="8.htm">Menu 8</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add snippet of what you are getting and what you want to help you

Comment: try align-items: center; instead of text-align: left;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of `text-align: left;` you should use:

```
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
```

as is customary in flex-boxes. Here it is inserted into your code snippet:

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #333;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: gold;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="logo" href="index.htm"><img src="styles/logo.png"></a>
  <a href="1.htm">Menu 1</a>
  <a href="2.htm">Menu 2</a>
  <a href="3.htm">Menu 3</a>
  <a href="4.htm">Menu 4</a>
  <a href="5.htm">Menu 5</a>
  <a href="6.htm">Menu 6</a>
  <a href="7.htm">Menu 7</a>
  <a href="8.htm">Menu 8</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it works now, but the problem is that logo is also centered and I want it to be on the left side of the navbar

Comment: your question has been linked to a proper answer, please refer to it